# Is it a clear code for database query

Tags: java

I am new to java language. I just want to make sure whether this code is nice and clean enough for my future project; I do not want this cause memory leaking in my application.

```
public Response returnAllPcParts() throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection conn= null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    String returnString = null;
    Response rb = null;

    try {
        conn = DatabaseConnection.databaseConn().getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * "+ "FROM r.order");    
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ToJSON converter = new ToJSON();
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

        json= converter.toJSONArray(rs);
        ps.close();
        returnString = json.toString();
        rb = Response.ok(returnString).build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(rs   !=  null) rs.close();
        if(ps   !=  null) ps.close();
        if(conn != null) conn.close();
    }

    return rb;
}
```

Comment: Do you have Java 7?  If so, I recommend the new "try with resources" syntax.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Code Review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks good. There could be problem if the ResultSet is to large. Try to  limit your resultset --> screen pattern. But it looks really good but you can always have improvements to code.

Comment: A `ps.close()` too much.

Comment: My concern is that in the `finally` block, if `rs.close()` or `ps.close()` throws an exception, then `conn.close()` won't run.  Also, why use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement` when there are no parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this code for a non-trivial project or application, I would recommend using something like [Spring JDBC](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-jdbcdaosupport-examples/) or some other helper library.
It clears most of the boilerplate code (i.e: the code for getting connection, closing result sets catch/finally blocks etc.)